# creating cut-out in the menu bar for logo

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding the cut-out in the middle of the menu using CSS.
Let me explain more: 
I have a menu with three "li" items on both sides and I want to put a logo in the middle of the menu and create a cut-out for it something like this:

[image]

The first thing that comes to my mind about how to get this, would be to divide the menu into the two parts - left side and right side. After that using "clip-path" try to modify the end of the left side menu and the start of the right side menu and using "position:absolute", put a logo in the middle of the cut-out, but I'm not sure about this solution. 
[image]

Maybe you can suggest something better?

The logo is transparent and the background image should be visible under the logo because the menu is on top of the image.

Screenshot from the design:
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to create a cut-out if you're going to cover it with an (round?) image anyways?

Comment: @RickardElimää I would like to have a border around image.

Comment: Maybe at this point, I could try to create a border going around image?

Comment: The better approach would be using rounded styled image and then you can position it wisely using CSS

Comment: @Utkarsh This would work, but I forgot to mention that background image in under the menu and logo itself is transparent so image should be visible in that little cut-out place.

Comment: @llinards can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: @Utkarsh please see updated post.

Comment: @llinards you can refer this for your solution (https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/)

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, I fully understand and I'm sorry if my post lead to think that I'm waiting for a ready solution. Purpose of this was to ask for maybe a different approach how to think in this kind of situation.

Comment: You could try chopping the menu up in three pieces and use a `radial-gradient` to create a background for the middle part.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to learn more about radial-gradients, so here could be a solution for your problem.

```css
:root {
  --background-cutout: 30px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-130deg, lightblue, red);
}

nav {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

nav > div:not(.middle) {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: cyan;
}

nav > div.middle {
  width: calc(var(--background-cutout) * 2);
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom, transparent 20px, aqua 21px); /* creates the "hole */
    
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* place .circle in center */
  align-content: end; /* place .circle in the bottom */
}

nav > div.middle > .circle {
  height: var(--background-cutout);
  width: var(--background-cutout);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* only needed because I used a border */
  border: 5px solid aqua;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<body>

<nav>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</nav>

</body>
```

Comment: Well, this is nice! Thanks!